# KML to shapefile Problems (ogr2ogr)

Tags: shapefile, gdal, kml, ogr2ogr

I want to use ogr2ogr command line to convert KML files to shapefile file, however, I can't get correct shapefile when I type the ogr2ogr convert command.

However, I can succeed in converting the continent.shp to correct KML file inside ArcGIS software by means of ogr2ogr. Besides, the conversion between acquired KML file in last step to shapefile.

I guess maybe my KML file is not the strict standard format. So I paste the KML file contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
  xmlns:xfdu="urn:ccsds:schema:xfdu:1" 
  xmlns:safe="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0" 
  xmlns:s1="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1" 
  xmlns:s1sar="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1/sar" 
  xmlns:s1sarl1="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1/sar/level-1" 
  xmlns:s1sarl2="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0/sentinel-1/sar/level-2" 
  xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Sentinel-1 Map Overlay</name>
    <Folder>
      <name>Sentinel-1 Scene Overlay</name>
        <GroundOverlay>
          <name>Sentinel-1 Image Overlay</name>
          <Icon>
            <href>quick-look.png</href>
          </Icon>
          <gx:LatLonQuad>
            <coordinates>-113.892487,68.977577 -124.235062,69.902451 -122.225281,73.452110 -109.974060,72.393707</coordinates>
          </gx:LatLonQuad>
       </GroundOverlay>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

I don't know the reason to the conversion problems. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: What you have is probably a KML SuperOverlay https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_21tutorial?hl=en#superoverlays. That is actually raster data that is georeferenced with a little KML file. I do not believe that GDAL can convert the KML part of a SuperOverlay into shapefile as it can do with KML that contains vectors.

Comment: Thanks for your  reply.However,I can achieve the conversion in ArcGIS Destop.

Comment: Sorry, KML SuperOverlay is actually a normal KML vector file and GDAL can find the geometry (polygon that represents the footprint of the image or "Icon") from the KML but it needs some fiddling. See my answer.

Comment: How about just taking out the image file (`quick-look.png`) and give it coordinates as GCPs? For instance there is another nice answer by @user30184 [jpg to geotiff transformation with gdal_translate and gcps fails](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142760/jpg-to-geotiff-transformation-with-gdal-translate-and-gcps-fails).

Comment: Eh, it's doesn't matter.

Comment: Maybe you give me a good method which convert jpg to GeoTIFF.However,I still have no answer for the ogr2ogr conversion failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion fails because GDAL is trying to read the data as GML instead of KML. You can see that this happens by running your command with GDAL debug flag.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" overlay.shp overlay.kml --debug on
...
GDAL: GDALOpen(overlay.kml, this=0000000002A479F0) succeeds as GML.
```

KML is XML as well as GML and now GDAL selects for some reason wrong driver for this data. Conversion succeeds if it is run with the GDAL_SKIP configuration option https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" overlay.shp overlay.kml --config GDAL_SKIP GML --debug on
...
GDAL: AutoSkipDriver(GML)
GDAL: GDALOpen(overlay.kml, this=0000000002420F10) succeeds as LIBKML.
GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(ESRI Shapefile,overlay.shp,0,0,0,Unknown,0000000000000000)
Shape: DBF Codepage = LDID/87 for overlay.shp
Shape: Treating as encoding 'ISO-8859-1'.
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'description' to 'descriptio'
Warning 6: Field timestamp create as date field, though DateTime requested.
Warning 6: Field begin create as date field, though DateTime requested.
Warning 6: Field end create as date field, though DateTime requested.
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'altitudeMode' to 'altitudeMo'
GDALVectorTranslate: 1 features written in layer 'overlay'
GDAL: GDALClose(overlay.kml, this=0000000002420F10)
GDAL: GDALClose(overlay.shp, this=0000000000420CF0)
```

What is odd is that ogrinfo opens the data correctly as KML without a need to skip the GML driver.

The shapefile contains the footprint of the image and a link to image file. There is really nothing more in the KML file. If ArcGIS finds something more, please tell what.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice,I have tried as you said.However, this method is not correct although I run with the GDAL_SKIP configuration option.

Comment: So what goes wrong? It does work for me.

Comment: The run process is normal as you displayed.However,the destination file is wrong.

Comment: user30184 think my KML may be SuperOverlay, however, I don't know the difference between them.

Comment: I  added a screen capture about what the converted shapefile contains. It looks OK for me.

Comment: Haha,emm,I believe in your normal shapefile output.

Comment: @Falcon_Baikal As your OP was asking for the method to convert your KML to Shapefile by ogr2ogr, I believe this is the correct answer. I suspect the reason you think it failure is because you wanted to see sentinel image on top of it.

Comment: Oh,my purpose is in shapefile rather than image identity.

Comment: I don't know how to paste an image here. I only got a .gfs format file.I don't know the format,but I open the file by notepad and there is '<GMLFeatureClassList />' few characters. I don't know the reason,  and I also know you can get correct file by ogr2ogr.        Anyhow,thanks for you.

Comment: That gfs file appears implies that data has been read by the GML driver. That's why I skipped the driver. What driver does the debug info report for you?

Comment: Wow, thanks for your rigorous attitude.When I was about to paste the debug info in the cmd window,I got shapefile successfully.I guess maybe I don't restart cmd command line contribute to the conversion failure by using your modification.  Thank u very much!!!